# Why injective matrix is bounded below?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, matrix-calculus

**Problem:** Let $A$ be a matrix with $m$ rows and $n$ columns. The matrix defines a linear operator, also denoted by $A$,
\begin{align}
A: \mathbb R^n & \longrightarrow \mathbb R^m\\
x & \longmapsto Ax
\end{align}
Assume that $n$ columns of matrix $A$ are independent (this is equivalent to say that operator $A$ is injective, see [the 3rd property here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Properties)), then operator $A$ is bounded below, i.e. there exists a positive constant $c>0$ such that
$$||Ax||\geq c||x||, \hspace{0.5cm} \forall x\in \mathbb R^n.$$
where $||\cdot||$ is the Euclidean norm.

**Motivation:** Above problem is a special case (finite dimensional case) of Theorem 2.5 in [this book](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-50), which stated that: *"A continuous operator between Banach spaces is bounded below iff it is injective and has closed range."* Regarding our problem, we know that:

- The operator $A$ is continuous,
- $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$ are Banach spaces,
- The operator $A$ trivially has closed range since we are working with finite-dimensional spaces.

Thus, the statement in our problem should hold true. In the proof of Theorem 2.5, they used the Open Mapping Theorem, which is a technical theorem! I am wondering are there any simpler proof with intuition and without Functional analysis for our special case. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Another way to see this is to notice that the function $$x\mapsto \|Ax\|$$ is continuous and hence attains its infimum on the compact set $\{x:\|x\|=1\}$.

Comment: @Ruy but the infimum can be $0$. While we expect that the infimum is strictly positive.

Comment: To say that the imfimum is attained is to say that there is some $x$ such that $\|Ax\|$ coincides with the infimum, hence it cannot be zero.

Comment: Ah ok you right, I now understand your idea, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If there exists no $c$ such that $\|Ax\|\geq c\|x\|$ for all $x$, then there exists a sequence $x_1,x_2,\dotsc$ such that $\|x_i\|=1$ for all $i$, and $\|Ax_n\|\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is finite-dimensional, its unit ball is compact, hence some subsequence $(x_{k_i})_i$ tends to a limit $x$ in the unit ball (by compactness). But $A$ is bounded and linear, hence continuous, so we get

$$\|Ax\|=\lim_i \|Ax_{k_i}\| =0$$

i.e. $Ax=0$ for an $x$ with $\|x\|=1$, which contradicts the fact that the columns of $A$ are independent.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much your nice answer!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on sequence {x_n} converging such that ||x_n|| to 0?

Comment: @LawrenceMano I think the answer is clear. Here $||x_n||=1$ for all $n$. $Ax=0$ implies $x=0$ due to injectivity. $x=0$ and $||x||=1$ give contradiction.