# A continuous linear map is bounded from below if and only if it is injective and has closed range

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I'm trying to prove a result mentioned in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3963268/why-injective-matrix-is-bounded-below) thread.

> **Theorem:** Let $E, F$ be Banach spaces and $f:E \to F$ linear continuous. Then $f$ is bounded from below, i.e.,
> $$
> \exists c>0, \forall x \in E: |f(x)| \ge c |x|,
> $$
> if and only if $f$ is injective and has closed range.

Could you have a check on my attempt?

**Proof:**

- Assume $f$ is bounded from below.

We have $f(x) = 0$ implies $c|x|=0$, so $\operatorname{ker} f = \{0\}$. Hence $f$ is injective. Let $y_n \in f(E)$ and $y \in F$ such that $y_n \to y$. There is a unique $x_n \in E$ such that $y_n = f(x_n)$. Then
$$
|y_n-y_m| = |f(x_n) - f(x_m)| = |f(x_n-x_m)| \ge c|x_n-x_m|.
$$

We have $(y_n)$ is convergent and thus Cauchy, so $(x_n)$ is Cauchy. Because $E$ is complete, there is $x\in E$ such that $x_n \to x$. Clearly, $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ or $y_n \to f(x) \in f(X)$. Hence $f$ has closed range.

- Assume $f$ is injective and has closed range.

Let $G := f(E)$. Because $G$ is closed, $G$ is a Banach subspace of $F$. Then $f:E \to G$ is bijective continuous between Banach spaces. By [open mapping theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4522800/another-generalization-of-open-mapping-theorem), $f^{-1}$ is continuous. The claim then follows.

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Comment: I would formulate the first part sligthly shorter not mentioning $y_n.$ Namely,  let $f(x_n)\to y.$ Then following your lines $f(x_n)\to f(x).$ Hence $y=f(x)\in f(E).$